# Woocommerce Create custom product type with variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, wordpress-theming, product-variations

I have a plugin for bookings that creates a new product type of WC_Product. I'd like to change this booking product type for variable booking product type (new product type of WC_Product_Variation or WC_Product_Variable), but have some errors when I change this product type to variable.

[image]

Comment: Include the actual formatted code instead of an image ;)

Comment: ... and describe the error you're getting